# Java object references issue

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I think I'm not understanding properly the way java works with the objects references. Here an example of the issue where I have realized something was not working as I thought:

```
public void UnequipObject(int index) {

    UsableItem ui = null;

    if(index == 0) ui = item1;
    else if(index == 1) ui = item2;
    else if(index == 2) ui = item3;

    if(ui != null)
    {
        int itemId = ui.GetId();            
        State.Instance().AddItem(itemId, 1);            
        ui = null;
    }
}
```

The function unequip an object of a character (I'm developing a videogame). Every character has a maximum of three objects. To make it more generic, with a given index, you unequip that object. For it, I copy in ui the object I want to unequip to make the changes in it. The State is not important here. The point is, when I do the assignement of "ui = null", it was supposed that the original object would be null too, as I thought that in the moment you assign the object to ui, both are the same reference and you can edit any of both that the changes will affect both at the same time...

Could anybody help me with this missunderstanding? Thanks!

Comment: You are just nulling one of the two references, the other one is still valid. Invoking methods on any of the two references will change the data in the original object (the thing both are referencing to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui` is a local variable. You are only setting *this* variable to `null`. You do not affect any other variables in your code. Later you assign `ui` to refer to one of the other items and do something with it.

On a side note, I strongly suggest that you use an array or List. This will make it easier to retrieve items (one line, rather than a bunch of if..else if..else's). It will also make it easier to add more "slots" to the inventory if you decide to do so in the future.

Comment: Yeah, well, it was made this way for a reason. About the missunderstanding, yes, I guess I was thinking too much about the references. It was obious!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an object to null. Yes, you set `ui` to `null`, but ui is just one reference to the object (there may be others refer to the original object). The object itself is not affected by this.

Only if there is no reference to the original object, will it be garbage collected.